# Find elements in a column that is not in another column of another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have two dataframes that look something like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:100))
dat2 <- data.frame(col2 = c(5:105))
```

I want to find all the elements that are in `dat` but not in `dat2`. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a filtering join, e.g.

```
dplyr::anti_join(dat,dat2, by = c("col1" = "col2"))
```

or directly via `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% filter(!col1 %in% dat2$col2)
```

Output:

```
  col1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setdiff`:

```r
setdiff(dat$col1, dat2$col2)
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
setDT(dat2)
dat[!dat2, on = .(col1 = col2)]
```

Output:

```
   col1
1:    1
2:    2
3:    3
4:    4
```